# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I keep getting different attribute errors when trying to run this file in ipython...beginner with pandas so maybe I'm missing something

Code:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

import pandas as pd

import json

nan=float('NaN')
data = []
with open('file.json') as f:
for line in f:
    data.append(json.loads(line))

df = DataFrame(data, columns=['accepted', 'user', 'object', 'response'])
clean = df.replace('NULL', nan)
clean = clean.dropna()

print clean.value_counts() 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Gotcha for future searchers: if you select a duplicated column name, you'll get a dataframe rather than a series!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) is a *Series* method rather than a *DataFrame* method (and you are trying to use it on a DataFrame, `clean`). You need to perform this on a specific column:

```
clean[column_name].value_counts()
```

*It doesn't usually make sense to perform `value_counts` on a DataFrame, though I suppose you could apply it to every entry by flattening the underlying values array:*

```
pd.value_counts(df.values.flatten())
```

Comment: it is not working when I am getting column through `iloc`

Comment: `value_counts()` is now a DataFrame method since pandas 1.1.0 -- posted another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004307/9379924

Answer (score 15):

To get all the counts for all the columns in a dataframe, it's just `df.count()`

Comment: `df.count()` produces a *different result* than `df['col'].value_counts()` aka `series.value_counts()`! But , your post is probably helpful for folks who want `df.count()`

Answer (score 11):

`value_counts()` is now a DataFrame method since pandas 1.1.0

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was working but now for some reason it is not. I replaced it with a groupby:

```
grouped = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count())
grouped.columns = ['Value_counts']
grouped
```

Answer (score 0):

value_counts work only for series. It won't work for entire DataFrame. Try selecting only one column and using this attribute.
For example:

```
df['accepted'].value_counts()
```

It also won't work if you have duplicate columns. This is because when you select a particular column, it will also represent the duplicate column and will return dataframe instead of series. At that time remove duplicate column by using

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
df['accepted'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using groupby(), just create a new variable to store data.groupby('column_name') then after take that variable and access that column again by applying value_counts(). Like df=data.groupby('city'), after you may say df['city'].value_counts(). This worked for me