# Value counts does not work for object columns

Tags: python, pandas

based also on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392226/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute), I try to count the frequency in a column. When I run it on a int64 column with:

```
df['value'].value_counts()
```

I get the desired outcome:

```
10000.00   2
50         1
....
```

Where when I run it on the object column:

```
df['text'].value_counts()
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

On top, if I run:

```
df.groupby('text').count()
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: Grouper for 'WHRG GEGENWERT' not 1-dimensional

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is duplicated columns names, here `text`, so after selecting get all dupe columns, so is returned `DataFrame` instead `Series` and raised errors.

Check it by:

```
print (df['text'])
```

If same values in each columns you can remove duplicates:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Comment: Yeah, I selected duplicates columns before I runned into this command, its fixed now.

Comment: @PV8 - there are same values in duplicated `text` columns?

Comment: Yes, I duplicated the complete column by mistake